# ¿Existe alguna alternativa ampliamente usada que sea más apropiada que "texto plano" para "plain text"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, adjetivos

Acabo de decirle a una persona no versada en la informática que me tiene que guardar un fichero "en texto plano", y se me ha quedado mirando con cara rara. Y claro, ya me he dado cuenta de que *texto plano* es una traducción a la ligera del inglés *plain text*.

Según el Merriam-Webster, *[plain](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plain)* significa "algo libre de artificios, ornamentos o materia extraña". Pero en la definición de *[plano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TKFR668)* del DLE no aparece ninguna acepción que se le asemeje.

Se me ocurre que una mejor traducción es *texto llano*, ya que *[llano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NTzc9dz)* significa "sencillo, sin ornamento alguno". Sin embargo, buscando en Google tenemos:

- "Texto llano": 28.400 resultados.
- "Texto plano": 446.000 resultados.

La diferencia de uso es considerable. ¿Existe alguna traducción mejor que "texto plano" para "plain text" que sea más ampliamente usada en el mundo hispanohablante?

Comment: texto llano me gusta - es una traducción directa que conserva el sentido y la intención en este caso. Otras variantes que usaría son: texto simple o solo texto.

Comment: También es frecuente ver "solo texto"

Comment: Yo uso indistintamente "solo texto" o "texto plano" algunas veces "texto sin formato"

Comment: Ten en cuenta que plano y llano viene de la misma raíz, son básicamente como el par *lugar* y *local*.   Pero otras opciones podrían ser *solo texto* o *texto puro*, iguales de breve y que transmiten la idea.

Answer (score 5):

`Solo texto` tiene 847.000 resultados [según Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22solo%20texto%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), y se usa en traducciones de Windows (al menos para Latinoamérica). Creo que aunque no es perfecta, captura la esencia.

Si se usa como complemento del nombre, [*de texto*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivo_de_texto#En_sistemas_Windows) parece ser suficiente: `archivo de texto`, `fichero de texto`, pues se sobreentiende que en ausencia de adjetivos no se espera algo distinto.

Answer (score 2):

> a una persona no versada en la informática

Siendo este el caso, puede que le sea más fácil entenderte si le dices que te lo guarde como "TXT" (*tequisté*), o en formato TXT. También le puedes decir "con extensión TXT" pero no te lo recomiendo, ya que más de un lego en la materia al decirle esto último lo que hace es guardarlo como sea y luego cambiarle manualmente la extensión a .txt :P

Otra expresión bastante usada es "texto sin formato", aunque me da la sensación de que se usa más en los propios programas (sobre todo en editores de texto) que por la gente cuando habla.

En cualquier caso, el 99% de los programas que pueda estar usando esta persona para guardar el archivo, a la hora de "Guardar como..." usarán alguno de los siguientes términos: "texto plano", "texto sin formato" o "solo texto". Y el 99% de los programas para Windows mostrarán junto a la opción indicada, la extensión "*.txt".

Comment: Pues no te creas, creo que fue cuando le dije que lo guardara como TXT cuando finalmente me entendió. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Si se toman en cuenta las alternativas que hay   al *plain text* que a la sazón son *csv : comma separated values* o también *tsv : tab separated values* respectivamente **valores delimitados por coma, tabulador** entonces la elección lógica y con menos ambigüedad debe ser **texto sin formato** o incluso **texto simple**

Hay que hacer la distinción, ocasionalmente en la codificación del texto mismo, pues estamos viviendo una transición del estándar ASCII al Unicode (UTF8). Un archivo de texto simple en ASCII, generará errores si el paquete que debe leerlo espera codificación UTF8 o viceversa. Windows para variar, codifica su texto simple en UTF16, pero las minucias de la codificación quedan fuera del alcance de este Stack.

> Baste con especificar el formato y codificación requerida (v.gr texto simple UTF8 o valores separados por comas, ASCII) para así dar una especificación sin ambigüedades.

En la práctica especificar la codificación es relevante si el archivo se género en una plataforma y será usado en otra. En la era de las PC, esto era lo más común. En la era de la nube, cada vez es más frecuente usar archivos en plataformas ajenas a las que los vio nacer.

Evidencia que apoya *texto simple* : los resultados del visualizador de ngramas en el corpus castellano: [texto simple se usa casi el doble de ocasiones que texto plano, aunque texto plano adquiere popularidad a partir de los 90s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Texto%20simple%2Ctexto%20plano%2Ctexto%20sin%20fornato&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctexto%20simple%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctexto%20plano%3B%2Cc0)

[image: visor de ngramas]